# How to add script tag in tinymce RTE Typo3

Tags: typo3

I have a typo3 site with version Typo3 4.5.29 and tinymcerte version 0.5.1

I have enabled the script tag in rte

Typoscript SETUP

lib.parseFunc.allowTags := addToList(object,param,embed,script)
lib.parseFunc_RTE.allowTags := addToList(object,param,embed,script)

TSCONFIG

```
RTE.default.proc.allowTags := addToList(object, param, embed,script)
RTE.default.proc {
allowTags := addToList(object, param, embed,script)  
  RTE.default.proc.HTMLparser_rte.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags  
  HTMLparser_db.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags  
  entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
}
```

Script tag works fine in Front-end and back-end too
But the it wont show source attribute 
It shows simply empty script tag

What is the exact issue ?
Any Idea ?